# acess element of NSArray with its index

Tags: ios, nsarray

Is it possible to access elements of an `NSArray` based on index and use them for comparison/operations?

Just like `arrayName[ith element]` in C/C++

Comment: also have you tried reading the documentation of `NSArray` before asking a basic question like this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Yes** , you can access elements of an NSArray based on index .

```
NSArray *a=@[@"s1",@"s2",@"s3"];
NSLog(@"%@",a[1]);
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
arrayName[yourIndex];
```

or

```
[arrayName objectAtIndex:yourIndex];
```

Comment: should be [arrayName objectAtIndex:yourIndex];

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

`[arrayname objectAtindex:yourIndex]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Index Subscripting Literal' that Apple Provide on iOS 6 SDK later

```
NSArray *array = @[1, 2, 3];
NSLog(@"%@", array[0])
```

Comment: subscripting has nothing to do with the SDK. It's a compiler feature.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella That is half true.  The syntax itself comes from the compiler, but the actual functions that implement it are part of the iOS 6 SDK (You only have to build with it, it will use some magic to insert itself into older versions at runtime)

Comment: @borrden, fair enough. I guess it's a matter of wording. Subscripting literals are a compiler feature, but Apple indeed started taking advantage on them from iOS 6 on.